# How to send ERC20 Tokens to multiple addresses?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, cpp-ethereum

I've been 2 days trying to do it, with no success.
I need to send Tokens to 1300 addresses that participated in the Bounty/Airdrop and I can't send manually one by one, that would take a lot of time and money.

I've deployed that on the testnet using MetaMask and Solidity Compiler:

> contract ERC20 {
>       function transfer(address _recipient, uint256 amount) public; }        contract MultiTransfer {
>       function multiTransfer(ERC20 token, address[] _addresses, uint256 amount) public {
>           for (uint256 i = 0; i < _addresses.length; i++) {
>               token.transfer(_addresses[i], amount);
>           }
>       } }

Later I sent 1000 ERC20 Tokens to it and tried to call the multisend function in MyEtherWallet. Then I put the PrivateKey from my wallet and press "Write", but nothing happens

[image]

Comment: this is not duplicate question lol...

Comment: if anyone else needs, answer is here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40970/distribute-token-to-multiple-address-not-working

Comment: there is a Dapp for it:
https://rstormsf.github.io/multisender/#/

Comment: updated URL is https://multisender.app